# How to reuse the same pattern on multiple svg circles in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have a project where we are pinning circles onto a world map by their lat/long.  Each circle should be/have/include/show an image: hasTheThing.png or doesNotHaveTheThing.png. As conditions in the app change, which circles get which image will change and need to be updated dynamically.

Right now my code is as follows.

```
  var defs = pointClustersG.append("defs");
  defs.append('pattern')
    .attr("id", "hasTheThing")
    .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
    .attr("width", "10px")
    .attr("height", "10px")
    .append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "images/hasTheThing.png")
      .attr("width", "10px")
      .attr("height", "10px")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0);
  defs.append('pattern')
    .attr("id", "doesNotHaveTheThing")
    .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
    .attr("width", "10px")
    .attr("height", "10px")
    .append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "images/doesNotHaveTheThing.png")
      .attr("width", "10px")
      .attr("height", "10px")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0);

  var point = pointClustersG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(allPointClusters)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
    .attr("class", "pointCluster")
    .attr("r", "5px")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { if(d.hasTheThing) { return "url(#hasTheThing)"} else { return "url(#doesNotHaveTheThing)"}});
```

No matter what I do to the x, y, height, width, and r values, the pattern repeats inside the circles.  But it repeats differently in each circle, leading me to believe this is something more than just not mathing out the locations and sizes correctly.  Wondering if just my code is wrong, or if it's my overall approach. And if it's option 2, anyone have suggestions on how to do this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing that you wrote yourself an answer, which is good and you are entitled to. But, just to explain, your problem...

> ... the pattern repeats inside the circles.

... can be fixed by setting the width and height of the `<pattern>` to 1 and removing `userSpaceOnUse`:

```
defs.append('pattern')
    .attr("id", "hasTheThing")
    .attr("width", 1)
    .attr("height", 1)
    //etc...
```

According to the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns):

> As with the gradientUnits attribute used above, patterns also have an attribute, patternUnits which specifies the units that these attributes will take. It defaults to "objectBoundingBox" as it did above, so **a value of 1** is scaled to the width/height of the object you're applying the pattern to. (emphasis mine)

Check this demo, using part of your code:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var defs = svg.append("defs");

defs.append('pattern')
  .attr("id", "hasTheThing")
  .attr("width", 1)
  .attr("height", 1)
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.pressunion.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/1-2.jpg")
  .attr("width", 140)
  .attr("height", 140)
  .attr("y", -30)
  .attr("x", -20);

defs.append('pattern')
  .attr("id", "doesNotHaveTheThing")
  .attr("width", 1)
  .attr("height", 1)
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/92/9d/3d/929d3d9f76f406b5ac6020323d2d32dc.jpg")
  .attr("width", 120)
  .attr("height", 120)
  .attr("x", -20)
  .attr("y", -10);

var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("circle");

circles.attr("cy", 60)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 50 + 90 * d
  })
  .attr("r", 40)
  .attr("stroke", "#222")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d % 2 === 0 ? "url(#hasTheThing)" : "url(#doesNotHaveTheThing)"
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! In case anyone is confused: this answers the question I actually asked here - useful to people.  My solution fixes the problem I had IRL which was not really explained in my question, and thus is useful to ... me.

Answer (score 1):

Experience has shown that the best way to find a solution to any problem is:

1. fight with it for 6 hours
2. post to SO
3. wait 5 minutes then magically figure it out yourself

Not sure how useful this is to anyone that isn't me, but just in case it can help:

```
var points = pointClustersG.selectAll("image")
    .data(allPointClusters)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "images/doesNotHaveTheThing.png")
      .attr("width", "10px")
      .attr("height", "10px")
      .attr("x",  function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("y",  function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
      .attr("class", "pointMarker");
```

That creates the following HTML:

```
<image href="images/doesNotHaveTheThing.png" width="10px" height="10px" x="695.1694728311688" y="625.5607912558139" id="3480" class="pointMarker"></image>
```

Since I'm using js/jquery and friends to decide which point needs what image, I'll just change the href value at the same time.